# Solve integral by multiplying by its variable

Tags: integration

I came across this integral and the first way I thought of solving it was by using something which I believe I saw somewhere. For example this: let R be the radius of some circumference (so R>0) - this integral

$$\int{1 \over \sqrt{R^2+x^2}}dx$$

could it be solved like this

$${1 \over 2x}*\int2x(R^2+x^2)^{-1 \over 2}dx$$

and then using the rule of subtracting 1 to the exponent and diving by that too (because it needs the derivative inside the integral)? I'm not sure, because in my way of thinking, it could work, though I would be limitting the function to x ≠ 0, instead of **R** as it was before, right?

--> Can this of multiplying and dividing by x factors be done? If it can't, why? (if we are multiplying and dividing by the same thing.) What are the implications if it can? (like 0/0 if x=0, maybe?)

Thank you in advance! (sorry if this is a basic question, also I don't know what to ask Google for it to direct me to an answer if there exists one already)

EDIT (because that thing up there is nonsense - lack of attention...):

$$\int{1 \over 2x}*2x(R^2+x^2)^{-1 \over 2}dx$$

Comment: You just can't take out terms of $x$ outside the integral

Comment: Actually I don't know how that crossed my mind. Forget that part haha. I'll edit the question and put it inside the integral.

Comment: Of course you can multiply and divide by $2x$ as long as $2x$ is nowhere close to being outside the integral

Comment: What am I missing on the part where I think x could be 0 and then it would be 0/0 - or at least something over 0? I have thought on in some time but I couldn't get to a point on that. For example, if you do that on a function or limit or other thing, you need to say that x must not be 0 after multiplying and dividing by x or it will be at minimum something over 0 (out of the domain) or maybe 0/0 (not sure on this one right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. We are certainly allowed to multiply the integrand by $\frac{2x}{2x}$. But we are not allowed to pull the factor $\frac1{2x}$ out of the integral: that variable $x$ only has meaning within the context of the integral $\int \cdots \,dx$.

(Also remember that you can *always* check your answers when finding an antiderivative of a function. Your proposal would yield the supposed antiderivative $\frac1x\big( (R^2+x^2)^{1/2}+C\big)$; is the derivative of that function equal to $1/(R^2+x^2)^{1/2}$?)

If one could do such a thing, then for example, we could use our favorite function-antiderivative pairs (say $\int \cos x\,dx = \sin x$) and then integrate *any* function $f(x)$ with the "calculation"
$$
\int f(x)\,dx = \int \frac{f(x)}{\cos x} \cos x \,dx = \frac{f(x)}{\cos x} \int \cos x \,dx = \frac{f(x)}{\cos x} (\sin x+C),
$$
which is nonsense.

Comment: Oh of course! I can't explain how it crossed my mind to actually pull an x factor out of it... Well, thank you for that as a start! haha Though, I actually didn't know we could multiply and divide even if inside the integral. Won't that affect the domain of integration or of function or something? Because if x is 0, it will come 0/0 - what am I missing on this?

Comment: Multiplying-and-dividing is just an algebraic step that we can do on any expression, regardless of where we find it (inside an integral, for example). Yes, we need to be careful about dividing by $0$; note however that an integral isn't sensitive to the value of a function at a single point, so isolated problematic points won't hurt us in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations!